# Powershell - export to csv, then import - compare-object shows all items as different

Tags: powershell, csv, compare, export-to-csv, import-csv

So, I found if I create an Array of AD user objects (Adding multiple AD-GetUser's to the same object) I'm getting strange results.

To replicate:

- Create an array of multiple ad-user properties (ie: `$array1`)
- Export: `$array1 | Export-csv -NoTypeInformation C:\temp\file.csv`
- Import it back in: `$array2 = Import-csv C:\temp\file.csv`
- Compare: `Compare-object $array1 $array2`
- See strange result:  All objects show changed (both directions).

For background, I'm checking a bunch of locked out users in AD -
So to put them in the array I'm doing:

```
foreach ($user in $lockedout)
{ 
    $array1 += @(Get-ADUser $user -Server $_ -Properties *)
}
```

Why am I seeing different results? I was hoping to put it to CSV, and import it on the next run to see what's new/changed.

Comment: So, I think I see WHY, I just don't see how to fix-   When I do a | Get-Member on the imported one, it shows all the Member-Types as "NoteProperties"  instead of "Property" with the proper Definition.  Anyone help on how to have it come through correctly?

Comment: Output them as CLIXml instead of CSV. Or, export and reimport the second array as a csv before you compare.

Comment: The Membert-types look better, but the Definitions are still off - a compare still returns every element.  I could export/import then compare, but I was hoping to understand better why it's acting this way.

Comment: We probably need to see more information then. How are you comparing? What does that code look like? What does the output look like? In what way is it "wrong"? What should it look like instead? Basically we need a [MCVE].

Comment: I also noticed a couple of irregularities in the bit of code that you did post. first, `-Server $_`. Why? $_ is a special variable available in pipeline code blocks. What is it's purpose here? Second, Get-ADUser is most like ly returning a single item in this situation. Why are you forcing it to an array?

Comment: CSV files do not support anything else than strings. In other words, if you`Export-Csv' and than `Import-Csv`, every property will be casted to a string (or simplified to it's typename). You will need another format to store complex data, like JSON or PSON

Comment: Wait, let's simplify a little here. Do you just want to know which accounts were locked last time compared to which accounts are locked this time?